# FFmpeg - Possible to scrub in FFplay window using lavfi?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

After some help on here earlier today, I'm able to get to `FFplay` to render a video with some filters using lavfi.  Here is an example of a simplified working command:

`ffplay -f lavfi "movie=d\\:/test.mpg"`

However, after using lavfi, I am now unable to scrub back and forth through the video within the `FFplay` window.

I expect this is because lavfi is decoding/rendering on the fly and doesn't have an index to allow for scrubbing.

Is there a way to force a timing understanding, or maybe a way to create an index for the lavfi rendered file?  ... Or am I missing something simple here that can be done?

Comment: Scrubbing isn't possible AFAIK, only seeking forward/backward in intervals of 1 second or 1 minute.

Comment: Are there hotkeys for seeking within FFplay after calling lavfi?

I've tried the typical FFplay hotkeys (arrows, s, etc), and they all seem to just advance by ~1 second, without the ability of seeking backward.

Comment: Ah, true, you cannot seek when a filter is applied. I think this is by design.

Comment: What's interesting is that I can scrub using FFplay with a basic filter (using `-vf`), but I can't once calling lavfi.  I'm wondering if the issue is because the file is unindexed?

Do you have any experience using FFindex?  I'm curious if that would help solve this isse.

Thanks!